# php make page edited by one user at time

Tags: php

I have a page that contains controls to edit some data. And I want to make this data editable only by one user at time. Users can see the content but can't edit it if this page is opened by some another user, so the priority to edit comes to the first user who opened the page. I need suggestions in how to realise this. 
Web server is nginx, if this is important.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan If I knew where to start my question wouldn't be so global. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
Make DB table --> create field at table [data_name lock];
User goes to edit page --> lock = 1;
User finish editing stuff --> lock = 0;
```

And when other user try to log in:

```
Test lock value --> if it`s 1 refuse enter, else it`s open to edit/view 
and so on.
```

.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you save your data in your database. You may add column that contains the ID of the user who is allowed to edit it (for example "last_author") with default value 0.

When some user opens the page you may set his ID to "last_author" and switch it back to 0 when the user exits the page.

When you load the page you just need to check if the given user matches the one who is logged in or if it's 0 the first user will get the edit permission.

This way you will know who is currently editing the page.

NOTE: You need to set some kind of cron job or to check the date of the opening of the page to make sure that some user will not just close his browser without the regular exit that allows you to set "last_author" to 0.

Comment: There's a slight issue here. If the data is saved in the db itself, it risks in getting quite large over a period of time, which could cause problems size wise. *Just saying*.

Comment: I don't mean to keep all edits (that's logs business). There should be only one field "last_author" for a given data set. For example if the table structure contains columns "id", "article_text", "last_author", "last_edit_time"  you just need to update it, not to create a new record.

Comment: I understand what you mean now; thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

if you save active session into database, the problem could be if the user close his browser without disconnecting from the session the session is still saved in database. So, you need to limit session's time in server side. And from client side (like AJAX), always tell to server if this client is still editing. So there is no interupting from second user if the first user session is expired but still editing.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need session, and a system to track if the file is open or not, and also a system to track if the file is "closed".

For example, when User1 is accessing the file, you write in the database that file1 is open by User1. So, next time a User wants to open the same file, you check in the database if the line with the FileId and UserId exists. If it does, you refuse access to User2. But you also need to check that User1 is still logged in, otherwise, if he closed his browser, the line will still be in the database and nobody will be able to edit the file, except him. At this point, you need to check that the User1's session is still active. If not, you remove the entry from the database and give access to User2.